# Bash passing keyboard input variables to awk

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script for a mini library for a homework and one of the request is to list books that have been rented by a user. I build the function like below, but how can i pass the $name variable to the awk command substitution on line 4? The library file has a format like this

title,author,user,date

```
function list_user_books {
echo Enter Name
read name
input=`awk -F, '$3=="$name"' $library | wc -l`
if (( $input == 0 ))
    then 
    echo No Books Found For This User 
else
for l in `awk -F, '$3=="$name"' $library`
do
    echo $l
done
stop=0
while (( $stop == 0 ))
do
    echo
    echo "=========================="
    echo "(t) Try again"
    echo "(b) Back to main menu"
    echo -n 'Choose Option to Continue'
  read reply
  case $reply in 
  "t") stop=1; list_user_books;;
  "b") stop=1; main_menu;;
  *) echo illegal choice, enter again:
  esac
done    
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `fi` to terminate the `if-else` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[bash_prompt$]l=hi; echo "hi there" | awk -v i=$l '$1==i'
hi there
```

the above example shows how -v option can transfer a bash variable to awk variable. You need to use this

Comment: ...and rather than piping to `wc`, it might be more efficient to do the counting in `awk` itself: `awk -v name=$name '$3 == name { wc += 1 } END { print wc }'`